# 2000 Chevy Silverado brakes drag badly

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, disk-brakes

When I drive the truck the brakes are dragging. I can park on a slight incline and the truck will not roll unless I press on the gas. I jacked up the truck and the wheels will not respond at all. The wheels Are very hard to turn. I just replaced a rotor on the front passenger side and the caliper. All the wheels were working fine And it drove fine for about a day. Now I am puzzled because all four wheels are not turning. Is there a chance it could be the master cylinder I’ve never heard of a master cylinder doing this. When jacked up you can’t really turn the front two wheels but with a lot of strength you can turn the back but not the front.

Comment: I just when out and the wheels unlocked and will roll now.  Could that still be the ABS?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this far more often than bad boosters causing it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the brake booster or the check valve. Start the truck, pump the brakes. If the are still locked after you release the pedal disconnect the vacuum hose to the booster. If the brakes release the check valve is bad. If the brakes are still locked pull the pedal up by hand or foot. If the brakes release the booster is bad.

Comment: Mikes, should I do this from a cold start? This morning I got in the truck and it’s not locked up. I will drive to work and respond later in the day on what they are doing.

Comment: Okay after about 15 to 20 minutes of driving the brake pedal is stiff and at the top with no slack and the wheels will barely roll. Could it be a proportionate valve.

Comment: The truck is off and sitting for around 2 hours I crank the truck and brakes work normal, If I leave the truck running it builds up pressure in the line and the brakes clap down on the rotors. This is insane!!

Answer (score 0):

Truck fixed!!!! I replaced the ABS Module (easy on my truck) and I drive the truck for a while and all okay. I drive the next day and again with the locking of all four breaks.
Stumped again. So now I loosened the master cylinder line bolts and this released the locked breaks. I then replaced the master cylinder and now all is good. Wether it was only the master cylinder or the master cylinder and the ABS module I will never know. I would recommend that if your breaks are locking up all four or just two unscrew the master cylinder break lines enough for fluid to drip out and see if that unlocks them like mine did.